# problemas al ejecutar programas con permisos de admin win 11

Tags: windows11

Usualmente cuando un programa de windows requiere permisos de administrador sale un recuadro solicitando estos, sin embargo en un equipo de marca dell recien entredo por mi empresa cuando ejecuto un programa que requiuera permisos de admin el pc no lo ejecuta y no solicita los permisos, solo lo ejecuta si yo de forma manual lo ejecuto con permisos.

Mi cuenta de usuario tiene permisos de admin